# ProtocolException calling WCF from a WF TransactionScope

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4

I'm getting a SOAP exception telling:
"The header 'OleTxTransaction' from the namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2006/02/tx/oletx' was not understood by the recipient of this message, causing the message to not be processed.  This error typically indicates that the sender of this message has enabled a communication protocol that the receiver cannot process.  Please ensure that the configuration of the client's binding is consistent with the service's binding. "

The method is defined as (by default has TransactionFlowOption.NotAllowed):

```
[OperationContract]  
Foo GetFoo(int fooId);
```

Other method in the same service is defined like:

```
[OperationContract]  
[TransactionFlowOption.Allowed]  
Foo GetFooTransactional(int fooId);
```

The first one would throw the exception when called within a WF TransactionScope activity, but not when calling it from a regular console application with a TransactionScope.

The second works in any case. I could just allow transactions in every method, but for several reasons I don't want to do that.

I'm using named pipe bindings allowing transaction flow in clients and server.
Server:

```
<netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding transactionFlow="true" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" transferMode="Buffered" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
</netNamedPipeBinding>
```

Client:

```
<netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding name="DefaultNamedPipeConfig" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          transactionFlow="true" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
         <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
         <security mode="Transport">
             <transport protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
         </security>
     </binding>
  </netNamedPipeBinding>
```

Comment: I have also tried refreshing the references and changing the IsolationLevel of the TransactionScope, but still getting the same exception. It looks like no matter what the contract says, WF activity is always expecting to call a transactional method (the call never arrives to the service, which means the framework is rejecting it because it doesn't understand the header)

Comment: If I use the wsHttpBinding protocol, I also get an error:
    The header 'CoordinationContext' from the namespace    'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/10/wscoor' was not understood by the recipient of this message, causingthe message to not be processed.  This error typically indicates that the sender of this message has enabled a communication protocol that the receiver cannot process.  Please ensure that the configuration of the client's binding is consistent with the service's binding.

Comment: [It seems to be a bug in the 4.0 release](http://connect.microsoft.com/wf/feedback/details/652836/protocolexception-calling-wcf-from-a-wf-transactionscope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It seems to be a bug in the 4.0 release](http://connect.microsoft.com/wf/feedback/details/652836/protocolexception-calling-wcf-from-a-wf-transactionscope)

Comment: It is usually good form to include additional information in the body of the post itself.  As it is the link is dead and there is no further information for anyone to use in a search.

Answer (score 0):

I updated Server and Client to .Net4.6.2 and the Error magicaly disapeared.
The Error showed up in my Development after the Server was updated from .Net 4.0 to 4.5.
I think this most of the time a .Net Version but can of course be a config issues as well. My Software was working fine before i had to update the Server because a DLL was updated to .Net 4.5.

GoodLuck